# aws Path-based load balancer not changing paths

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-application-load-balancer

I have a system where I use a load balancer to do path-based redirects where depending on the path, it will redirect to a different domain or EC2 app.
8
The way I have it set up now, all HTTP requests get forwarded to HTTPS, and that works fine.

For all HTTPS requests, I want it so that a path to [www.abc.com/](http://www.abc.com/)* always gets redirected to [www.abc.app/](http://www.abc.app/)* EXCEPT for one path, which is [www.abc.com/game](http://www.abc.com/game)

I have two listeners setup:

1. [www.abc.com/game](http://www.abc.com/game) gets routed to a target group that is linked to an EC2 instance hosting a nodejs app. I can access this through port 3000 fine using the native EC2 IP. This is the highest priority listener
2. The last priority listener takes the HTTPS://#{host}:443/#{path}?# pattern and redirects it to [www.abc.app/](http://www.abc.app/)*

The issue is, listener #1 seems to be completely ignored because the [www.abc.com/game](http://www.abc.com/game) path gets redirected to [www.abc.app/game](http://www.abc.app/game) instead of routing it to the EC2 server.

I checked my conditional logic and I have it as the following:
If abc.com/game OR [www.abc.com/game](http://www.abc.com/game) OR variations containing the "https" prefix then redirect to EC2 target group

Is there any clue as to why this listener is not triggering?

Comment: You use the term "redirect" many times in your question, but redirects are when the load balancer just tells the browser to go to a completely different address, instead of sending the request onward to a target EC2 instance. When the load balancer actually sends the traffic to the target group (and on to the EC2 instance) it is called forwarding.

Comment: thanks for the terminology correction

Comment: I'm not trying to be pedantic, it just makes your question extremely difficult to read and understand what you are actually trying to accomplish, because you are using the wrong terms. AWS Application Load Balancers can do both redirects, and traffic forwarding, and from your question you appear to be trying to do traffic forwarding based on path rules, but you keep calling it redirects, so it is confusing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set the rule to have a `host header` condition and then a `path` condition as in the screenshot below:

[image]

This is the high priority rule. You can also forward if there is any suffix to */game* by using below rule:

[image]

Comment: this is so close. The redirect now happens as appropriate but now my EC2 target group says is unhealthy and I don't know why

Comment: The redirect now happens as appropriate but the page is just blank. Additionally I get a certificate is not valid message even though my load balancer has an AWS issued certificate attached to it. 

When i go to the console I see this error message: 

Access to internal resource at 'https://www.example.app/manifest.json' (redirected from 'https://www.example.com/manifest.json') from origin 'https://www.example.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

Comment: @somethingstrang. the page being blank is due to missing supporting files like `.css` and `.js` not being served from the same rule. You will need to have a check on such supporting files to load the page. If they are served from other paths, it is better to include them towards your target.

Comment: The second CORS error is related to what I have mentioned above. Here in this case, the `.json` file request is not hitting the **Forward-Rule**. Its gets the `redirect` response which browser will throw as an error as the CORS header is not covering. You don't need to worry about the header for now. Find out the files that are needed to load the page, and then include them in your `Forward` rule or create multiple forward rule as needed.

Comment: For the missing supporting files, when I enter the IP:3000 direct from EC2, I see the application fine. I wonder if I need to change the route in my frontend code to reflect the /game path?

Comment: ill make a new issue since this one resolves it technically

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78227221/aws-load-balancing-forwarding-to-ec2-app-shows-a-blank-page